# Custom Font Size : Increase and Decrease in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, font-size

In my flutter application, I have to provide an option to change the font size of the application Text contents.

So, normally, I know that for different screen sizes, We can manage but this is not that case.

I have just gone through this plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

But, It's not the case which I am looking for.

**The case is to choose particular font size option and according to selected option the font height should be change.**

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to change fontsize in your application you could do something like this.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
double? _fontSize = 14;

void _changeFontSize(double fontSize) {
 setState(() {
   _fontSize = fontSize;
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'FontSize is now: $_fontSize',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _changeFontSize(22), child: const Text("22")),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _changeFontSize(24), child: const Text("24")),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _changeFontSize(26), child: const Text("26")),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

Comment: I don't need to change a single value. Overall app's font should increase and decrease acording to previously selected value from drop down.

Comment: @JaiminModi Well i think you can do it if you change the ElevatedButton to a dropdown, store the selected value in a local database and read it globaly. I am not sure, but i think you could do something with TextTheme and use it all over the app https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html,  I think it will work but maybe not what you are looking for..